# handle JSONException from HttpResponse

Tags: java, exception, httpresponse, jsonexception

I have a method which needs to act based on response from an other service.

The expected response is `{"status":"success"}`

I have 2 methods in my java code.

```
String getResultParam( HttpUriRequest request ) {
    JSONObject res = getResult( request );
    return res.getString( "status");
}
```

---

```
JSONObject getResult( HttpUriRequest request ) {
    String res = // process the request and get the response String
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(res);
}
```

The first is a generic method to execute any request and get the response string as a JSON. Here, `new JSONObject(res)` throws a JSONException.

The second method needs to get the `status` from the JSON after executing the request.Here, `res.getString("status")` again throws a JSONException.

How should I handle these exceptions?

- Do I need to propogate the exeception as `throws JSONException` to all the methods using this method?
- If I do need to propogate the exception to all the methods calling this method, where would be the point where I catch and handle the exception?
- Do I need to catch the exception in the same method and throw a runtime exception?
- Do I return `null` on the generic method?

What would be the proper design to handle this Exception? Any advice would be appreciated.

### I'm using Tomcat Server, and not Spring.

Comment: if you are using spring then use ExceptionHandler annotation which will handle exceptions .

Comment: no I'm not using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to handle or throw a runtime exception in more specific methods you can see some java API from that you learned the designs with java is following the way java codes, handle the exception, etc.

Comment: Yes, my problem is on how to actually handle the above exceptions which **might** be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

1) propogate the exeception as throws JSONException to generic method

2) catch Exception and throw failure response or throw generic Exception

```
String getResultParam( HttpUriRequest request ) {
    try
    {
        JSONObject res = getResult( request );
        return res.getString( "status");
    } catch(Exception e){
    // Or Throw new  GenericException(e);
        return res.getString("failure");
    }
}
JSONObject getResult( HttpUriRequest request ) {
    String res = // process the request and get the response String
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(res);
}
```

Comment: the `getResult` method also has an IOException thrown. How would I handle the propogation of that exception?

Comment: Catching Exception will automatically catch IOException too.

Comment: I read that catching should be done as specific as possible, and also IOException should be considered generic to `getResult` I suppose?